# Oracle cast PL/SQL table to SYS_REFCURSOR

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to access one my `Stored Procedure` from java code, where the procedure is returing a `PL/SQL table(PACKAGE TABLE) type`, as it is easy to handle `SYS_REFCURSOR` in my java code, I am trying to convert the `PL/SQL table to SYS_REFCURSOR` in my Stored Procedure. After googling I didn't got any appropriate answer for this conversion. Can someone help me out for this conversion logic?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE     TESTPROC(
  INPUT1 IN VARCHAR2,
  INPUT2 IN VARCHAR2,
  P_PRC OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS 
  PACKAGE_TABLE PACKAGE.TESTTABLE;
BEGIN
  PACKAGE_TABLE := FUNCTION_RETURN_PACKAGE_TABLE(INPUT1, INPUT2);
  -- **LOGIC TO CONVERT PACAKGE_TABLE TO SYS_REFCURSOR GOES HERE**
END TESTPROC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TABLE` operator for this

```
create or replace PROCEDURE     TESTPROC(
  INPUT1 IN VARCHAR2,
  INPUT2 IN VARCHAR2,
  P_PRC OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS 
BEGIN
    OPEN P_PRC FOR
        SELECT * FROM TABLE(FUNCTION_RETURN_PACKAGE_TABLE(INPUT1, INPUT2));
END TESTPROC;
```

But you should keep in mind that you have to have schema level pl\sql table type (for oracle <12c). Also notice that `SELECT * FROM` brings you one-feild rows with your-plsql-table-row-type value.

Comment: I getting error `Error(9,25): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type`

Comment: First of all it looks like you have package level table type `PACKAGE.TESTTABLE`. It is appropriate for oracle 12c only.

Comment: Is is possible to loop through the `PACKAGE_TABLE`

Comment: I am just asking a suggestion, if it possible to loop through, I think we can store it in `SYS_REFCURSOR` right?

Comment: You can loop on it in pl\sql code but you can't build refcursor on it. You can for exaple loop your package level type table and put data to a temp table and then take refcursor on it but it is a ugly idea IMHO. Why don't you want just use schema level pl\sql table type?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101612/discussion-between-agent5566-and-suganthan).

Comment: I having restrictions in doing so, that why

Comment: Sorry, I am in office network where chat is not possible.

Comment: Just click the link to the chat, it is a part of Stackoverflow

Comment: Sorry again, I am getting access denied from my network

Comment: So you are saying by converting the having a schema level table, I can able to overcome issue right?

Comment: Yes, after moving the package level type to schema level type, the issue got fixed. Thanks